# Multiple test conditions in jQuery template "if"

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-templates

How can I test multiple test conditions using jQuery template "if"?
For example, in any language I would do something like:

```
if(str1=='abc' && str2=='def'){
    //do something
}
```

But how can it be done using jQuery template "if" clause? I tried following but it doesn't work.

```
{{if str1=='abc' && str2=='def'}}
    //do something
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create some helper function in order to check multiple "AND" conditions. On the other hand, `||` (OR) can be done this way: `{{if x===1 y!==2}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

AND statements

```
{{if $data.str1=='abc' && $data.str2=='def'}}
    //do something
{{/if}}
```

Similarly OR statements

```
{{if $data.str1=='abc' || $data.str2=='def'}}
    //do something
{{/if}}
```

Reference:https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl/issues/70